# iwconfig wlanX channel ... - SET fails due to device being busy

Tags: wireless-networking, ifconfig

I'm using a Debian Jessie on a Sony Vaio VPCEB3M1E. Some information about my wireless card:

```
:~$ sudo ifconfig
wlan0 IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"********"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: C0:25:06:F1:0B:F3   
      Bit Rate=39 Mb/s   Tx-Power=14 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:8   Missed beacon:0

:~$ lspci | grep -i wireless
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

I'm trying to manually adjust the channel and maybe the TX power (currently it's at 14dBm) my adapter uses for transmitting information to the router. So first of all I did a check to see which channels it provides and which I'm currently running (yes, the information is also displayed using `sudo ifconfig` ;)):

```
:~$ sudo iwlist wlan0 channel
wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
      Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
      Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
      Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
      Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
      Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
      Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
      Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
      Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
      Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
      Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
      Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
      Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
      Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
      Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
```

Next thing I did was to shutdown the interface:

```
:~$ sudo ifconig wlan0 down
```

Running `sudo ifconfig` showed me only my Virtualbox adapter along with `eth0` for my Ethernet. So I thought that the interface is really down. However

```
:~$ sudo iwconfig wlan0 channel 11
```

returned

```
Error for wireless request "Set Frequency" (8B04) :
SET failed on device wlan0 ; Device or resource busy.
```

I've tried also using `sudo ip link set wlan0 down` but still same error.

I've read that on the Internet that this might be to a running `ifplugd` which blocks the interface. However upon executing

```
:~$ sudo service ifplugd stop
```

I got that no such service is running.

I know that I usually have to wait for some short period of time after executing the command for shutting down an interface however even after 10 minutes of waiting nothing changes and the error still occurs.

Am I doing something wrong here?

PS: I'm actually pretty surprised that the card supports the `802.11n`. I always thought it supported only up to `802.11g` and had some really naughty thoughts about the people at Sony.